# Remove the default browser header and footer when printing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, printing-web-page

I got an HTML with the `<body onload="window.print()">`.

The question I'm trying to ask is:

- Is there any way to remove the strings that the web browsers add to the printed page?
- Such as:

  - Web site from where the page was printed
  - Page count
  - Title of the web page
  - Date of printing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Docs is now [skirting around](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=50089) this issue by generating a PDF version of your document.

If you are using Chrome, it will automatically open the PDF in a new tab and pop up the print dialog. Other browsers will prompt you to download the resultant file (which is not necessarily obvious behavior).

While I don't find this to be an elegant solution, one should be able to recreate this fairly easily using most existing web technologies.

Answer (score 9):

These a usually browser specific print settings.

In IE & FireFox for example you can go into page setup and change the header and footer details for printing.

I don't think this can be controlled by the web page itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can employ an activeX-plugin if your users uses IE, an example is scriptX from Meadroid: http://www.meadroid.com/sx_intro.asp

Answer (score 3):

For future reference:

```
@page {
  margin: 0;
}
@media print {
  footer {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  header {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this css code

```
@page {
    margin-top: 0cm;
    margin-bottom : 0cm;
}
```