# Javascript HTML Window Print Issue

Tags: javascript, html, function, printing, window

I am using window.print() Javascript function for my HTML page to print, but it inclues `Page URL` and `date in footer` by default into the print or print preview.

Any quick solution, might be some patch in JS or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove the headers/footers programmatically. Visit [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1421429.aspx) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255534/remove-the-default-browser-header-and-footer-when-printing-html)