# JavaScript window.print() function with excessive details

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

On my html page, I have a button with an onClick function `window.print().`

When users press this button (in Chrome) it opens the default printer interface but in the header of the page and in the footer there are some excessive information.

In header, it prints out date and index.html as the name of the html file. In footer it prints the location of index.html file on my computer (C:://...).

How to disable this and print the page as it is presented in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome it's possible to hide this automatic header/footer using

```
@page { margin: 0; }
```

Source and More Solution:

- [Remove header and footer from window.print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print)
- [how to remove print header/footer with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710315/how-to-remove-print-header-footer-with-code)

Hope this helps.