# CSS, HTML - Why does the content of the page title tag (<html><head><title>THIS CONTENT</title>...) appear when printing my page?

Tags: html, css, printing, title

I'm writing a page using HTML, CSS, jQuery and some PHP to run on my localhost. I use a separate stylesheet for printing. In print preview now, the content of the page's title tag

```
<html><head><title>THIS CONTENT</title>...
```

shows up on the page - How to get rid of it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the header you set in the print settings, depending on your software, OS and/or print driver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove the default browser header and footer when printing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255534/remove-the-default-browser-header-and-footer-when-printing-html)

Comment: It's not the header (nor the footer) created by the browser that bother me. But, before the first content element of my page, I find the page title text. How come ...?

Comment: With the given data, it seems that the issue is caused by your style sheet. You really need to show your style sheet to get help with the issue.

Comment: Well. Now inserted `title { display: none; }` into the print.css - working. Thanks for your time, guys, didn't guess one would CSS-format header elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send a `text/html` header from PHP. Add the following to the **beginning** of your file, before anything else is output to the browser:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html"); ?>
```

Comment: Done, but to no avail. I'm using PHP only in the body, all header elements are HTML code.

Comment: Thanks, DC_. I got it solved (and will close the question asap, new account) -- inserted `title { display: none; }` into the print.css ...

Answer (score 0):

I inserted

```
title { display: none; }
```

into the print.css and now it works. Thanks for your time, guys, didn't guess one would CSS-format header elements.

(How do I upvote Jukka's comment? It made me revisit the CSS thought and helped me solve this. @Jukka: Greetings from Helsinki)