# Remove Headers from CKEditor Print/Preview

Tags: header, ckeditor, print-preview

I have a CKEditor on my website, and I would like it so that when the user clicks on the printer icon, the headers don't print and only the text inside of the editor is printed on the page.

This is the site: http://strawberrycv.com/4.php

For example, if you go to the site and click print, the top will say "Rich Text Editor, editor1" (in the left corner) and the date/time (in the right corner).  Is there a way to remove these?

Answer (score 0):

These are browser-specific headers, not added by CKEditor. You can't really control the browser-specific print headers I'm afraid, see this for futher details and a weird workaround: [Remove the default browser header and footer when printing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255534/remove-the-default-browser-header-and-footer-when-printing-html)